# How do I take a image from a folder and make it into a background using background-image?

Tags: html, css

So I am working on this practice website and my folder is set up to have my images all in their own folders. My problem is when I want to take that image and use it as a background using the `background-image` in css and I cant take it from their without making it have its own URL. So I am wondering if there is anyway I could pull an image from a folder using `background-image`

My current CSS if that helps

```css
/* Welcome Styling */

.web-welcome-background {
  width:50%;
  filter:brightness(40%);
  background-image: url('images/front-page-welcome.jpg');
}
```

Currently this is not working and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a static file server. That is, a piece of software that will make your local filesystem available over HTTP.

An easy way to get a file server up and running is to install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then in your terminal, run the command below.

```
npx serve
```

That will use [serve](https://github.com/zeit/serve), a project by Zeit. There are many other options though, both inside and outside of the Node.js ecosystem.

Once you have a file server running and reload your page, the background image should appear, assuming that the filepath is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Welcome Styling */
.web-welcome-background {
    width:50%;
    filter:brightness(40%);
    background:url("images/front-page-welcome.jpg");
}
```

> make sure the images folder exists and is accessible

Comment: So I gave that a try and the image still didn't pop up on my website.

Comment: This is the html part `        <div class="web-welcome">
            <p class="web-welcome-subtitle">Welcome to</p>
        </div>`

Comment: like this `<div class="web-welcome-background"> <p class="web-welcome-subtitle">Welcome to</p> </div>`

Comment: If that doesn't work make sure you a targeting the correct image path, or use an absolute path like http://www.yourdomain/images/front-page-welcome.jpg. Even try viewing the url in the browser url bar to make sure the image exists where you think it does.